# MFP 8.0 SECURITY_CHECK_NOT_FOUND

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-cli, mfp

I had configured my security adapter. 
I had mentioned the security check name in my app side also.

**This is MFP server version: 8.0.0.00-20160822-2140**

**MFPdev_CLI version: 8.0.0-2017102406**

(It was working long day back. is there any problem with my app and server-side versions? Only mfpdev-cli has updated recently.)

Please see the logs

```
{ status: 400, statusText: "Bad Request", responseText: "{"errorCode":"SECURITY_CHECK_NOT_FOUND","errorMsg":"Invalid Security Check RegisteredClient"}", responseJSON: {…}, responseHeaders: {…}, …} errorCode : "SECURITY_CHECK_NOT_FOUND" errorMsg : "Invalid Security Check RegisteredClient" responseHeaders : {connection: "Close", content-type: "application/json", date: "Sat, 03 Mar 2018 09:26:29 GMT", transfer-encoding: "chunked", x-powered-by: "Servlet/3.0"} responseJSON : {errorCode: "SECURITY_CHECK_NOT_FOUND", errorMsg: "Invalid Security Check RegisteredClient"} responseText : "{"errorCode":"SECURITY_CHECK_NOT_FOUND","errorMsg":"Invalid Security Check RegisteredClient"}" status : 400 statusText : "Bad Request"
```

**Thanks**

Comment: Check if  you have missed  deploying  ResourceAdapter  to the server.
Adapter code is here [link](https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/SecurityCheckAdapters/tree/release80).

Also see if you have done Scope-Elements Mapping in server  correctly

Comment: See here [Mapping scope elements](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHSCD_8.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_scope_elements_mapping.html)

Comment: Ya, it was working (before 2 months). Now I re-switch that branch in my git. Only my cli-sdk has been updated. No other changes in security flow.

Comment: If your cli-sdk is updated then you should also update your  MFP 8.0 server to the latest .As suggested by  Vivin ,updating to the latest server should resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The MFP Server version which you are using is not compatible with the MFPDev CLI Version as the new Client SDK contains the Default OAuth Scope and Dynamic App Authenticity changes. Please try with MFP Server build which is greater than febraury 2017, This should resolve the issue which you are facing.

More info on default scope changes and MFP Minimum Server version for client SDKs version `8.0.0.00-20170216-202020` or later is [here](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2017/03/09/8-0-ifix-release/).

Answer (score 1):

You see this message `"Invalid Security Check RegisteredClient"` because you are using a very old build of MFP 8.0 server, but your client SDK is much later.

Update your server level to the latest and this issue will go away.